# „Haben Sie etwas [mit/aus/?] Fisch?”

Tags: word-choice, preposition

If asking a shop keeper if they have any food (baguette, wrap etc.) containing fish, what is the proper way to ask?

I usually use one of the following:

> Haben Sie etwas mit Fisch?
>
> Haben Sie etwas aus Fisch?

I am not sure if either of these are correct and sometimes the shopkeepers have a hard time understanding me.

From the answers in this [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10311/aus-vs-von-what-is-the-difference) and some examples, I am more inclined towards *aus*  but would like to know the proper preposition and would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: Are you asking for Fischstäbchen or a piece of fish with side dishes?

Comment: I'm referring to common snacks available at take-away shops at train stations (Baguette, Sandwich or Wrap etc.)

Comment: Then the answers apply fully. I was half joking because you make Fischstäbchen (and other things) "aus Fisch" (hopefully). So the question with "aus" might make sense, too, depending on context; the typical take-away waiter would probably be confused, though.

Comment: he would rather consider me just another ignorant foreigner ;)

Comment: Nah, many Germans don't speak proper German, anyway. In Pfalz, say, the guy would expect you to say (roughly, I'm no Pfälzer) "Hasche ebbes mit Fisch?" and would think "Diese Leute von überm Weißwurstäquator sprechen schon komisch." Besides, most immigrants skrew up articles and prepositions all the time (it's really tough...) so tourists probably won't stand out too much. ;) For a humorous take on this, I recommend [Kaya Yanar's "Made in Germany](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=made+in+germany+kaya+yanar).

Comment: @Raphael I have experienced this article/grammar problem with immigrants in Germany as well (although as an exchange student I mess it up just as much). Usually the vendor and I repeat ourselves over and over again, neither of us understanding each other, getting louder and louder, and then we switch to English briefly and it turns out. Mistakes of grammar in Germany aren't so grave unless someone is in a rush... then they will be more direct.

Comment: @PatrickSebastien There are definitely people who are touchy when (apparent) foreigners make grammar mistakes; hopefully not a majority. (To be fair, I tend to be a bit snarky if a person who has been living in a country for 10+ years speaks the language worse than the average visiting student.) Personally, my usual problem is pronounciation, esp. if the speaker is from Asia (i.e. has a completely different language background). I can adapt to some extent, but that takes longer than a few sentences. So I guess my advice would be to focus less on grammar and more on clear pronounciation.

Comment: IMO German pronunciation is as easy as learning a few rules (I before E, E before I, switched sounds of S and Z and so on). The easiest things should be learnt first and practiced so that if you even screw up grammar, the listener has something that can tell them what you are talking about. I have been told numerous times I can speak good German but the reality is, I just try to say words like Germans do. Other than that, I have poor vocab and grammar but it's working for me

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Definitely "mit".
"Aus" is appropriate if the thing is made *from* that material. A table is "aus Holz" and a window is "aus Glas". Beer is made "aus Hopfen, Malz, Hefe und Wasser". 
But all these things have been transformed to become what they're now.
A sandwich made "aus Fisch" would mean that the bun is made from fish, the cheese is, too and there's fish as a topping. 
So... for ingredients... use "mit", unless it is really a transformational process like with beer.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, definitely "mit". "Aus ..." would be "made of".

> A toy made of wood = Ein Spielzeug aus Holz
>
> A sandwich with ham = Ein Sandwich mit Schinken

Answer (score 6):

**MIT** would be best expressing contains.
**AUS** means the major part is eg. fish, a baguette *aus* fish would not be bread but fish