# "Von", "vom" or "aus" in a sentence like "Warm greetings from Cape Town"?

Tags: preposition

I'm always confused when to use *von*, *vom* or *aus* in a sentence, such as "Warm greetings from Cape Town", so which do I use in this case?

Comment: I would use `aus` in this example but i am not sure if a generilization can be made. `aus` would also be the word to use to describe where you come from or the material something is made out of. `vom` is just `von dem` and `von` is used in cases as `von denen habe ich seit lang nicht mehr gehört` (i haven't heard from them in a while). But as my name suggests, i am not a native speaker so let's wait and see what the others say.

Comment: Unfortunately more context is needed for a general answer. In your specific example neither *von* nor *vom* is needed: *Liebe Grüße aus Kapstadt*.

Comment: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/10311/1224 — And there are many, many sources on the Internet that covers that topic.

Comment: Kaapstad or Kapstadt?

Comment: In englischen Sätzen würde ich generell nichts von dem benutzen. Grüße aus Berlin.

Comment: I edited the question. In English it's Cape Town, in German Kapstadt.

Comment: Thanks so much everyone for the advice, it is very helpful from all you. I now have a clear idea on this little grammatical teaser and what to use in which context.

Answer (score 7):

Ev. Kounis' comment is correct:

"*Aus*" is used when you are "*in*" something while "*von*" is used when you are "*bei*", "*über*", "*auf*" ... something.

For male and neutral words with article "*von dem*" becomes "*vom*". (There is no short form of "*von der*", "*aus dem*" or "*aus der*".)

City and country names typically have no article and you are "*in*" a city or "*in*" a country. Therefore "*aus*" is correct.

Examples:

> Grüße **aus** England (England is a country and you are **in** a country.)
>
> Grüße **aus dem** Mustermannhaus (You are **in** this house when writing this message.)
>
> Grüße **vom** Mustermannhaus (You are **near** this house when writing this message.)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Martin Rosenau's answer, I'd like to add:

The fact that you can greet *aus* locations you are *in*, would make countries, cities, houses, etc locations you greet *aus*.

> Grüße aus dem Kölner Dom (when you are inside)
>   Grüße aus England
>   Grüße aus Kapstadt
>   Grüße aus dem Haus meiner Großeltern

If you are *on* or *at* that place you greet from, you greet *von*, like islands, sights, etc.:

> Grüße vom Kölner Dom (when you are in front of it or on one of the towers)
>   Grüße von Koh Samui
>   Grüße vom Kap der guten Hoffnung
>   Grüße vom Haus(dach) meiner Großeltern

This is just a rough generalization, but it will be a good advice for most cases. Please feel free to add edge cases to the comments for discussion.

Comment: Very enlightening Thorsten, you've been a great help to sort out my query. Many Thanks :)