# "aus" or "von" when we refer to places where we come from?

Tags: preposition

I read from my textbook that we should use "aus" when we refer to places where we come from, e.g. ich komme aus dem Kino/Theater.

But I also saw that sometimes we use "von" to refer to places where we come from. E.g. vom Rathaus, von der Bank.

What is the subtle difference between the two? And how can I decide when to use which?

Comment: Answered here: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10311/aus-vs-von-what-is-the-difference?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

**Aus** -  if you go outside of a place you went into before.

> Ich gehe in den Laden. Ich komme aus dem Laden.

**Von** - if you go outside a place where you haven't for sure 
entered inside it.
E.g. Bank (you can only use the ATM):

> Ich gehe zur Bank, ich komme von der Bank.

Also businesses with a name z.b McDonalds.

> Ich gehe zu McDonalds, ich komme von McDonalds.

Another example is meer which isnt inside a building or a

closed area:

> Ich gehe ans Meer, ich komme vom Meer.